# php blob to picture in joomla module in 1 Script

Tags: php, joomla, module, blob

I have pictures in a database and i want to read it out and display it as a picture.
However i get strange long charakters as result.

my code:

```
<?php
/**
* @version 1.0 $
* @package HelloWorld
* @copyright (C) 2010 BlaBlbb
* @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
*/

/** ensure this file is being included by a parent file */
defined( '_VALID_MOS' ) or die( 'Direct Access to this location is not allowed.' );
 // assemble query
$query = '
    SELECT *
    FROM artikel
';

$database->setQuery($query);
if ( !$database->query() ) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
         alert('".$database->getErrorMsg()."');
      </script>";
} else {
$rows = $database->loadObjectList();
}
echo '<table>';
foreach ($rows as $rowi)
{

echo '<tr><td>'.$rowi->Artikelname.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$rowi->Stueckpreis.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$rowi->Gewicht.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$rowi->Lagerstand.'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$rowi->Aenderungsdatum.'</td>';
echo '<td><img>'
.$rowi->Foto.
echo'</img></td></tr>';


}
echo '</table>';
?>
<!--<h1>Hallo Welt</h1>
<p>Das ist ein Test</p>
<p>juhuu</p>
-->
```

any suggestions?
i wanna have the image in the same file if possible...
i am very new to joomla so i dont know how to use it with a second php that creates the picture...

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing strange characters because you're just echoing the raw image data into the page.  In order to serve an image, the browser must request it *as a file* from the server*.

This means that you need to either need to:

1. write your image data to disk, then give the browser the URL to the file in the `<img>` tag, or
2. you need to create a script that returns the proper `Content-type` header for the image type and echos the image data then give the browser the URL to the script in the `<img>` tag.

*: (Yes, there's `data:`, but that's not a suitable solution for most cases.  Especially this one.)